# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm using a select query in hql. But i cannot use in my API.

Getting error as

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
```

Can Someone tell me wat is the error in My HQL

**My Code**

```
Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
//Query query = session.createQuery("from Login where email='" + email + "' and password='" + password + "'");
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name, a.mobile,  a.email, p.patientId\n"
        + "FROM ( from login where email= '\" + email + \"' and password= '\" + password + \"') a\n"
        + " INNER JOIN\n"
        + " patientprofile p ON a.loginId= p.loginId");
List<Login> logins = query.list();

session.close();
return logins;
```

Comment: you are using two varible with the same name `query`! what is your problem?

Comment: First of all, you can't call 2 variables with the same value, and which is the query that you are trying to list?You know which is giving you the error?

Comment: no no first one is commented out..

Comment: You may want to add a select in the inner parenthesis, between the FROMs.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid HQL syntax, Check http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First : `\n` is unecepted in the queries so you have to remove them.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name, a.mobile,  a.email, p.patientId "
        + "FROM ( from login where email= '" + email + "' and password= '" + password + "') a "
        + " INNER JOIN "
        + " patientprofile p ON a.loginId= p.loginId");
```

Second : concatination is not secure instead you can use `setParameter` to avoid syntax error and SQL Injection :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name,"
        + "a.mobile, a.email, p.patientId "
        + "FROM ( from login where email= :email and password= :password) a "
        //----------------------------------^----------------------^
        + "INNER JOIN "
        + "patientprofile p ON a.loginId= p.loginId");
query.setParameter("email", email);
query.setParameter("password", password);
```

Third : i really don't understand this part of query `( from login where email= :email and password= :password)` this can make another problem, make sure you are using the correct query! it can be :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name,"
            + "a.mobile, a.email, p.patientId "
            + "FROM (SELECT l from login l where email= :email and password= :password) a "
            //---------------^-----------^
            + "INNER JOIN "
            + "patientprofile p ON a.loginId= p.loginId");
    query.setParameter("email", email);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
```

Forth : I would like to use a native query instead, because both HQL and JPQL accept **Subqueries** just in SELECT, WHERE or HAVING clause so you can use :

```
Query query = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT a.mobile, a.email, p.patientId FROM "
        + "(SELECT * from login l where email= :email and password= :password) a "
        + "INNER JOIN patientprofile p ON a.loginId= p.loginId");
query.setParameter("email", email);
query.setParameter("password", password);
```

---

read more about this in [JPQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_subqueries)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 90 [SELECT CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name, a.mobile, a.email, p.patientId FROM (SELECT l.loginId, l.email, l.mobile from login l where email= :email and password= :password) a INNER JOIN patientprofile p ON a.loginId= p.loginId]

Comment: @mree and where are the `p` in your query? did you mean to change p to a ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 90 [SELECT CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name, a.mobile, a.email, p.patientId FROM (SELECT l.loginId, l.email, l.mobile from login l where email= :email and password= :password) a INNER JOIN patientprofile p ON a.loginId= p.loginId]

Comment: Can Somebody Help me with this Query?? Help me out

Comment: you have to ask your self a question, what your query should to do @mree?

Comment: That i know.. First of all I need to check Email and password And based of that I will get Loginid.. Then (SELECT l.loginId, l.email, l.mobile from login l where email= :email and password= :password) This Query I need to join with patientprofile table abd get the column name as shown..

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name, a.mobile, a.email, p.patientId FROM (SELECT l.loginId, l.email, l.mobile from login l where email= 'pqr@gmail.com' and password= 'pqr@1') a INNER JOIN patientprofile p ON a.loginId= a.loginId;

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name, a.mobile, a.email, p.patientId FROM (SELECT l.loginId, l.email, l.mobile from login l where email= 'pqr@gmail.com' and password= 'pqr@1') a INNER JOIN patientprofile p ON a.loginId= p.loginId;

Comment: @mree can you try to test without `CONCAT(p.FIRSTNAME, ' ', p.LASTNAME) as Name,` ?

Comment: @mree you can ask another question about the query, i already answered about the error you get, now it is another problem, so its better to separate problems in different questions!